# Is there a way to encapsulate personal certificate, intermediate root and trusted root in a portable file?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

Is there a way to encapsulate a personal certificate, intermediate root and trusted root in a pfx file for use in a c# program for SSL/TLS x509 encyrption?

I was given a file to install in the "Trusted Root", a file to install in the "Intermediate Root" and a file to install int he "Personal" certificate area.   Then I have to load the certificate and add it to a web service call.

For deployment purposes, is there a way to include everything needed in one pfx or p7b file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PFX / P12 file can contain the server certificate, the intermediates and the private key so you can use it to store the keying material for your ssl/tls connection

P7B can contain only certificates but not private keys, so it is not suitable